# Mascara no muestra decimales con 0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo esta clase que uso como Mascara de números

```
public class Mask implements TextWatcher {

    private DecimalFormat df;
    private DecimalFormat dfnd;
    private boolean hasFractionalPart;

    private EditText et;

    public Mask(EditText et)
    {
        df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
        df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        this.et = et;
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        try {
            int inilen, endlen;
            inilen = et.getText().length();

            String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
            Number n = df.parse(v);
            int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
            if (hasFractionalPart) {
                et.setText(df.format(n));
            } else {
                et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
            }
            endlen = et.getText().length();
            int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
            if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
                et.setSelection(sel);
            } else {
                // place cursor at the end?
                et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // do nothing?
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // do nothing?
        }

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
        {
            hasFractionalPart = true;
        } else {
            hasFractionalPart = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Mi problema es que funciona todo correctamente , Separa los miles con la COMA ","

por ejemplo 5,300

Los decimales también andan bien

por ejemplo 5.33

lo que si no funciona es que si quiero escribir 5.01 , no me deja poner un 0 por delante , ni tampoco por detrás osea , 5.10 , solo me escribe 5.1 , agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: `mi problema es que funciona todo correctamente` Me provocaste un problema existencial xd

Comment: Significa que los miles , osea 5000 , lo deja 5,000 , ahora los decimales por ejemplo 5,000.12 , esto lo hace correcto , pero si quiero escribir , 5000.01 , no me deja escribir el 0 adelante , ni tampoco alrevez  , 5,000.10 , me deja 5000.1 y no puedo poner un 0 para completar el 10

Comment: df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##"); cambia eso por df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

Comment: Si lo cambie por eso , pero al realizar dicha accion , al escribir . ya te agrega el doble 00 , y no te deja borrarlos para escribir tranquilo , tenes que ir con el dedo a posicionarte adelante y poner el dedo y lo mismo para el segundo cero , ah que me refiero con esto , al ponerlo asi , si escribo 0. automaticamente me pone 0.00 , y no deja borrar los .00 , debo posicionar el foco de escribir adelante de cada .00 para poder cambiarlos , nada practico

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag los ceros después del punto decimal no son validos, se tienen que guardar estos ceros finales y agregarse cuando se aplica el formato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> si quiero escribir 5.01 , no me deja poner un 0 por delante , ni
>   tampoco por detrás osea , 5.10 , solo me escribe 5.1 , agradezco
>   cualquier ayuda

En este caso no es suficiente cambiar el formato, en realidad la modificación del valor se esta realizando dentro de `afterTextChanged()` ya que una fracción con 0 no es valida, lo que se tiene que realizar es almacenar los ceros finales y agregarse cuando se aplica el formato.

Puedes ver una solución realizada por [SAM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267661/sam) en su respuesta:

[No se puede ingresar cero después del punto decimal en Android EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547801/unable-to-input-zero-after-decimal-point-in-android-edittext)

Lo que realiza es precisamente almacenar en un `StringBuilder` los "ceros finales" en el caso de escribir algún cero después del punto decimal , basándonos en esa solución se aplica a tu clase:

```
public class Mask implements TextWatcher {

    private DecimalFormat df;
    private DecimalFormat dfnd;
    private boolean hasFractionalPart;
    private int trailingZeroCount;

    private EditText et;

    public Mask(EditText et)
    {
        df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
        df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        this.et = et;
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        try {
            int inilen, endlen;
            inilen = et.getText().length();

            String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
            Number n = df.parse(v);
            int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
            /*if (hasFractionalPart) {
                et.setText(df.format(n));
            } else {
                et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
            }*/
            if (hasFractionalPart) {
                StringBuilder trailingZeros = new StringBuilder();
                while (trailingZeroCount-- > 0)
                    trailingZeros.append('0');
                et.setText(df.format(n) + trailingZeros.toString());
            } else {
                et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
            }

            endlen = et.getText().length();
            int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
            if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
                et.setSelection(sel);
            } else {
               // place cursor at the end?
               et.setSelection(et.getText().length() -1 );
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // do nothing?
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // do nothing?
        }

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        int index = s.toString().indexOf(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()));
        trailingZeroCount = 0;
        if (index > -1)
        {
            for (index++; index < s.length(); index++) {
                if (s.charAt(index) == '0')
                    trailingZeroCount++;
                else {
                    trailingZeroCount = 0;
                }
            }

            hasFractionalPart = true;
        } else {
            hasFractionalPart = false;
        }
        /*if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
        {
            hasFractionalPart = true;
        } else {
            hasFractionalPart = false;
        }*/

    }

}
```

de esta forma puedes escribir como ejemplos:

```
5.01
5.10
5000.01
5000.10
```

---

Agrego un ejemplo de como usar la clase de @BrunoSosaFastTag

```
 EditText edtext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
 Mask mask = new Mask(edtext);
 edtext.addTextChangedListener(mask);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge , de verdad estos días me as salvado de unas cuentas , sos el numero 1 ! , Ojala en un futuro pueda estar a tu nivel ! , funciono de 10 , Gracias capo

Comment: Excelente Bruno, en un futuro espero compartas más de tus conocimientos en el sitio, saludos!.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te comenta [Ajeno](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15897/ajeno) funciona correctamente, con una pequeña puntualización:

```
df = new DecimalFormat("#,###0.000");
```

Debería de mostrártelo de forma correcta.

Comment: Lo probare de esta forma gracias

Comment: Si te sirve, márcala como aceptada.

Comment: Aun no eh podido probarlo pero no te preocupes en cuanto lo pruebe vengo a responder

Comment: @aalf1987 en verdad probaste esta solución? el formato es modificado en los métodos del TextWatcher ya que después del punto decimal, el 0 "no tiene valor".